# Using filp/whoops as a service provider in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to integrate the `filp/whoops` package into Laravel 5.1 app.

Installed the package like this:

```
composer require filp/whoops:~1.0
```

Created `app/Providers/ErrorServiceProvider.php` like this:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;
use Whoops\Run;

class ErrorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $whoops = new Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new PrettyPageHandler);
        $whoops->register();
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

And registered the service provider in `config/app.php` like this:

```
'providers' => [
    App\Providers\ErrorServiceProvider::class
]
```

But I'm still seeing the default error pages.

Comment: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/bringing-whoops-back-to-laravel-5

Comment: Thanks @JeremyHarris. But I'm looking how to use it as a service provider to avoid editing `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around editing that file. That is why it is in the `app/` directory, is so you can edit it. The situation is the same with integrating BugSnag, you have to modify that file.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I got confused by this post which seemed to get it working without editing `Handler.php` https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/whoops-removed-from-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

run composer dump-autoload then your problem solved

Comment: Already tried `composer dump-autoload` but still same old error page.